# How do I use the `If` `then` `else` condition in json schema?

Tags: jsonschema

A relatively new addition to JSON Schema (draft-07) adds the if, then and else keywords. I cannot work out how to use these new key words correctly. Here is my JSON Schema so far:

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "bar": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "if": {
        "properties": {
            "foo": {
                "enum": [
                    "bar"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "required": [
            "bar"
        ]
    }
}
```

If the "foo" property equals "bar", Then the "bar" property is required. This works as expected.

However, if the "foo" property does not exist or input is empty then I don't want anything. how to acheive this?

```
empty input {}.
```

Found Errors:
Required properties are missing from object: bar.
Schema path: #/then/required

I use online validation tool:

https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Comment: You may not feel that formatting is important, but it helps people answer your question. The linked online validator even has a button to auto format your JSON for you. Please use it.

Comment: The phrase "I dont want anything" doesn't make any sense. Can you rephrase this? I've assumed you mean, "I do not want any values in the object". Is that correct?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `if` keyword means that, if the result of the value schema passes validation, apply the `then` schema, otherwise apply the `else` schema.

Your schema didn't work because you needed to require `"foo"` in your `if` schema, otherwise an empty JSON instance would pass validation of the `if` schema, and therefore apply the `then` schema, which requires `"bar"`.

Second, you want `"propertyNames":false`, which prevents having any keys in the schema, unlike if you were to set `"else": false` which would make anything always fail validation.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "bar": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "enum": [
          "bar"
        ]
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "required": [
      "bar"
    ]
  },
  "else": false
}
```

Comment: How I can use "AND" or "OR" operation in "IF": ?

Comment: You can wrap subschemas in `allOf` for "AND", and `anyOf` for inclusive OR, and `oneOf` for exclusive OR.

Comment: Can you give me an example, If foo = "Vu" AND bar = "Dung" then true else false ?

Comment: Oh, that's actually quite simple, you don't even need additional applicators. You can simply add another key to your `properties` keyword. The WHOLE of the subschema value for `if` must pass validation.

Comment: I'm not really catch up. Currently, I used allOf: [{ if: ... then ... }, { if: ... then ....}], but now in the first `if` condition, I need a AND comparing. That my issue

Comment: Maybe you could post a new question? Just make sure to use the `jsonschema` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use the "else" property ?

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": { "type": "string" },
        "bar": { "type": "string" }
     },
     "if": {
        "properties": {
            "foo": { 
              "enum": ["bar"] 
            }
        }
    },
    "then": { 
      "required": ["bar"]
    },
    "else": {
      "required": [] 
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work if the key `foo` is not included in the JSON instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use classical If-Then-Else construction or nested if needed.
Here is some documentation https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals#ifthenelse
And example where Variable0 - Variable5 is what you want to check and required_field[number] what field will be requred if Condition is True

```
{
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "Variable0": {
            "const": "Yes"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "Variable1": {
              "const": "Yes"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "Variable2": {
                "const": "Yes"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "required": [
              "required_field2"
            ]
          },
          "else": {
            "if": {
              "properties": {
                "Variable3": {
                  "const": "Yes"
                }
              }
            },
            "then": {
              "required": [
                "required_field3"
              ]
            },
            "else": {
              "if": {
                "properties": {
                  "Variable4": {
                    "const": "Yes"
                  }
                }
              },
              "then": {
                "required": [
                  "required_field4"
                ]
              },
              "else": {
                "if": {
                  "properties": {
                    "Variable5": {
                      "const": "Yes"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "then": {
                  "required": [
                    "required_field5"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If json schema in html file, you may use such php construction.
Considering that in html file json is a simple string, we may use such `php` language construction as `echo` to output any additional strings depending situations or conditions.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Product",
  "image": "image",
  "description": "description",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Brand",
    "name": "brand"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "url": "url",
    "priceCurrency": "currency",
    "price": "5000",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition"
  }<?php if ($aggregateRating) echo ',' ?>
  <?php if ($aggregateRating) echo '
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "' . $ratingValue . '",
    "ratingCount": "' . $ratingCount . '",
    "bestRating": "' . $bestRating . '",
    "worstRating": "' . $worstRating . '"
  }';
  ?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73137125/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)