# required field based on other field value

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Consider the following json:

```
"test": {
      "required_key" : ["a", "b"],
      "a": {
          "key": "val"
      }
  }
```

I want using json-schema-validator to require that the values of "required_key" that is: "a", "b" will be required under the "test" tag.

That is, I want to declare required tags based on value of other tag ("required_key")

**In my example the validation should fail since "b" appear on the "required_key" but is not defined inside the "test" tag**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the \`If\` \`then\` \`else\` condition in json schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539586/how-do-i-use-the-if-then-else-condition-in-json-schema)

Comment: You can only do this if you know all the possible values. You cannot dynamically reference part of the instance JSON in the Schema.